# Run through file until *string* and then read columns until *no decimal*

Tags: c++

I have a file looking like

```
some header
this is the first block
                         1    2    3    4
                         5    6    7    8
                         9   10   11   12
this is the second block
                         1    4    7   10
                         2    5    8   11
                         3    6    9   12
this is the third block
                         1    2    3    4
                         5    6    7    8
                         9   10   11   12
```

I want to read this file and check for the words "first", "second" and "third" in order to read the following blocks of numbers into arrays so I can plot them later. For example I would only want to read in the colums 1 and 2 of the second block. The main problem is that I can't accomplish to read in until the third block starts. It stops reading after the first line of the seconds block. In a simple way my code looks like this.:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

std::string line;
std::vector<double> vector1;
std::vector<double> vector2;
double v1;
double v2;
double v3;
double v4;

ifstream infile ("myfile.txt");
while (std::getline(infile, line)){ 
  if (line.find("second",0) != std::string::npos){    // when "second" is found start to read block.
    while (line.find_first_of("123456789.") != std::string::npos){    // while the next line is not a number continue reading. THIS DOESN'T WORK !
      infile >> v1 >> v2 >> v3 >> v4;
      vector1.push_back(v1);
      vector2.push_back(v2);
      std::getline(infile, line);
    }
  }
}
infile.close();

cout << "Vector1" << "  " << "Vector2" << endl;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++){
  cout << vector1[i] << "  " << vector2[i] << endl;
}
```

The expected outcome would be:

```
Vector1  Vector2
1        4
2        5
3        6
```

But I get:

```
Vector1  Vector2
1        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the double read inner and exiting the loop,

```
ifstream infile ("myfile.txt");
while (std::getline(infile, line)) { 
    if (line.find("second",0) != std::string::npos) {
        while (infile >> v1 >> v2 >> v3 >> v4) {
            vector1.push_back(v1);
            vector2.push_back(v2);
            // note getline is removed, else double reads on break.
        }
        // this may be needed if you plan on reading anything else.
        infile.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the clear documentation, but what exactly is it good for here?

Comment: When using `operator>>` for input, upon failure, an error is set and must be cleared before it can be used again. If you're only loading a single block it's not an issue, but if within the same loop you were scanning for "first" and "third" as well, you'd need to clear before reading the next block.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.
The first one is after reading the numbers, the "read cursor" stays right before the end of the line. Then, when you call getline, you end up with an empty line. This is a common problem when mixing line-reading methods with other input methods. It happens with mixing gets and scanf, and also when mixing streams' >> operator and getline.

The second one is you're reading an entire line, then reading again the numbers from the file. If you read a line of text, you must read the numbers from that line you read and not get new input from the file. So try this one:

```
std::getline(infile, line);
while (line.find_first_of("123456789.") != std::string::npos) {
  std::stringstream stream(line);
  stream >> v1 >> v2 >> v3 >> v4;
  vector1.push_back(v1);
  vector2.push_back(v2);
  std::getline(infile, line);
}
```

Comment: hm when I do that I get an endless loop

Comment: Sorry about that, read your code too fast and didn't get that there was another error. I updated my answer, try it now :) Remember to include <sstream>.

Comment: This one won't stop after block 2. But I guess in this way my idea of `while (line.find_first_of("123456789.") != std::string::npos)` doesn't quite do the job here.

Answer (score 1):

I am rather surprised you get that result. If line contains 'second', then does not contain any digit and you cannot enter the if.

I would change the body like this:

```
ifstream infile("myfile.txt");
while (std::getline(infile, line)){
    if (line.find("second", 0) != std::string::npos)
    {    // when "second" is found start to read block.
        while (infile){    // while the next line is not a number continue reading. THIS DOESN'T WORK !

            infile >> v1 >> v2 >> v3 >> v4;
            if (!infile)
                break;
            vector1.push_back(v1);
            vector2.push_back(v2);
            std::getline(infile, line);
        }
    }
}
```

So when you detect 'second' keep reading numbers. When number reading fails `if (!infile)` exit the loop

Comment: actually me too. I had an std::ignore statement before but then I realized I didn't need it. The line was skipped automatically somehow. Your approach seems to work.